# Computation of semistable model of curve over DVR of mixed characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

given a stable curve $C \in \overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}(K)$ over a field $K$ and an DVR $R$ with fraction field $K$ and algebraically closed special point, is there a general technique to compute a curve $C' \in \overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}(D)$ with generic fibre $K$? As $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}$ is proper, such a $C'$ exists and is unique, but I cant see a straight forward way to compute such a $C'$.

The example I am currently working with is the elliptic curve $y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$ in mixed characteristic with residue characteristic $2$. Modulo $2$, the curve given by this equation has a singularity worse than a node at $x=\sqrt \lambda$ and if I blow it up, I end up with a genus $0$ curve, so I somehow need to attach a genus $1$ component and there must be canonical way to do so, but I do not see how.

Comment: If $K$ is algebraically closed, then $R$ cannot be discretely valued (what would be the square root of its uniformizer?).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this mistake, I think the question now should be well-stated.

Comment: In the new version, the stable reduction $C'$ will in general exist only after passing to a finite extension of $K$, due to the stackiness of $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$.

Comment: I would blow up the arithmetic scheme rather than blow up the mod $2$ curve. In other words $2$ should appear in the ideal you are blowing up. This way you will never lose a component.

Comment: If I blow up the point in the arithmetic surface, I blow up a codimension 2 subscheme, so I think the blown up scheme will not be flat anymore and therefore I will not get an element of $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{g,n}}$?

Comment: There's no reason blowing up a codimension $2$ subscheme should destroy flatness.